# Blazor Server Component - How to two way bind input html tag and call function onchange

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am trying to figure out how I can both two bind to an HTML input and call a function for the onchange event.

```html
  <input id="nonce" type="hidden" @bind="@nonce" @onchange="Checkout" />
```

This gives the following error: *The attribute 'onchange' is used two or more times for this element. Attributes must be unique (case-insensitive). The attribute 'onchange' is used by the '@bind' directive attribute.*

One solution might be to not use the bind directive and instead use the onchange to update the value in the input.

Or can I override the onchange the @bind is using and add my own custom code?

Answer (score 0):

> One solution might be to not use the bind directive and instead use
> the onchange to update the value in the input.

This.

Depending on how you're using this, you might be able to do stuff in the `get; set;` for the property `nonce` as well, though technically trying to set a value doesn't guarantee that it's changing.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the model value in `OnInitialized` method and then change it by `@oninput` event. Now, you can customize the `@OnInputChange`.

You can use the below code:

```
<input value="@Value" @oninput="@OnInputChange" />
<h4>@Value</h4>

@code {
BlazorRoom Room = new BlazorRoom
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Room 1",
    IsActive = true,
    Price = 499
    
};



public string Value { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();

    Value = Room.Name;
}


private void OnInputChange(ChangeEventArgs args )
{
    Value = (string)args.Value; 

    //you can customized it
    Value = Value.ToUpper();       
}
}
```

and the model is:

```
public class BlazorRoom
{
    public int Id { set; get; }

    public string Name { set; get; }

    public decimal Price { set; get; }

    public bool IsActive { set; get; }        
}
```